# User logged in as wrong user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, autofac, form-authentication

I am using MVC3 along with Autofac & EF4.1 to build an secure web app deployed on two servers.

A very few users are experiencing a strange issue where user is logged into system as wrong user with different account/branch settings.

I am authentication user using form authentication(.ASPXAUTH cookie) and roles are decided from active directory contents. user being logged in is assigned an unique token which flows during all transaction.

Could this be related to Autofac or authentication cookie is cached somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was actually a static image file having set-cookie inside which was causing the trouble.

Comment: How did this affect the login?? I guess the image file did not set a cookie named .ASPXAUTH with another users encrypted Authentication data?

Answer (score 0):

Are you users using shared computers?

If so, then I suspect that the cookie is to blame.

If not, then context information somewhere else in the application is to blame.

Comment: users are not using shared computers for sure. This is happening to 1 in 100 users accessing the site.